# The argument type 'Future<bool>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget' [Flutter]

Tags: firebase, flutter, widget, future

```
Future _alertDialog(BuildContext context, {String isi, AlertType alert}) {
return Alert(
  context: context,
  type: alert,
  title: "Notification",
  desc: "Laporan telah masuk, silahkan menunggu email dari admin!",
  buttons: [
    DialogButton(
      child: Text(
        "OKAY",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
      ),
      onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(
        context,
      ),
      width: 120,
    )
  ],
).show();
}
```

Hello, im still new in flutter, I want to try to make alert dialog in another class so i make it portable class to use the alert easily.

For example,
I create the `alertDialog.dart` , i want to call `alertDialog.dart`inside the `main.dart`.
But I got error

> The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'

for the alert i use another depedencies

```
rflutter_alert: ^2.0.2
```

I'm trying this because i dont understand about context, i always get

> looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

is there any solution for this ?
thank you before !

Answer (score 0):

The function `_alertDialog` returns a `Future`, so what do you expect? You cannot use `_alertDialog` in your widget tree since it's not a widget but a function. Instead, call `_alertDialog` as the `onPressed` property of a button or something similar.

I assume, `Alert(/*...*/).show();` returns a future because it's waiting for user response such as clicking a button. The future probably completes, when `() => Navigator.pop(context)` is called in the `onPressed` method of your `DialogButton`.

Comment: Well, i do understand about it if the widget returning Future<bool>, but i thought it would be more portable then just make the alertDialog in every file i have, like in main.dart  i make new alert, in the another screen i make new alert. So I thought it would be really helpfull if i can make it into a new file so easily call it.

Comment: You‘re totally right, it‘s also better style to move widgets and related methods in separate files. I just don‘t understand why it‘s still not working, to be honest. Do you still get an error if you call _alertDialog(/*...*/) in the onPressed handler of a button?

Answer (score 0):

showing alert function can be void

```
void _showAlert(BuildContext context) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Wifi"),
            content: Text("Wifi not detected. Please activate it."),
          )
      );
    }
```

Comment: Well yes, I do use Future<void> or just make it by name like _showAlert(BuildContext context) without any method name, but thank you for answering !